# Role of seed in random number generation

Tags: java, random

I have a big question in my mind:

I can use a seed number to generate random numbers:

```
Random rand = new Random(34666666);
```

But the thing that I cannot understand is the role of that seed. For example what is the difference of

That code with the following:

```
Random rand = new Random();
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation#Computational_methods

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you supply a specific, hard-coded seed, to the [one-arg `Random` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random-long-), the random numbers that will be generated will always be the same, every time you run the program.  That is needed when you need a predictable source of random numbers.

However, when you don't supply a seed, then the [`Random` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random--) will choose a seed for you, based on `System.nanoTime`.  The random numbers will be different every time you run the program, because the seed will be different each time.

> Creates a new random number generator. This constructor sets the seed of the random number generator to a value very likely to be distinct from any other invocation of this constructor.

This is important because Java's random number generator is pseudo-random; each new pseudo-random number affects the seed that is used for the next pseudo-random number that gets generated.

Answer (score 2):

The seed allows you to get a determined sequence of random numbers.

It is especially useful when you need to generate random numbers but also be able to launch again and obtain the same results.

Without a seed, the constructor chooses one for you depending on the time when the `Random` object is instanciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the code for java.util.java (http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/Random-source.html), you will see that the constructor uses the current timestamp for its seed:

```
public Random()
{
  this(System.currentTimeMillis());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest reading the Java Documentation on Random.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

Some important bits:

`If two instances of Random are created with the same seed, and the same sequence of method calls is made for each, they will generate and return identical sequences of numbers.`

```
public Random()
Creates a new random number generator. This constructor sets the seed of the random number generator to a value very likely to be distinct from any other invocation of this constructor.
```

Answer (score 1):

The Java random function is this:

```
numberi+1 = (a * numberi + c) mod m
```

The number is your seed.

The random is not really a random number, if I know your current number then I can know all of the numbers you'll get in the future. (this is why you should always use a static random and never create a new random (you will get the same number))

If you need a more secure random,
use the SecureRandom class of java.

It provides you with a more secure random that uses stuff like, number of movements the mouse made, the current location of the mouse, number of seconds since to last typed and so on...