# Java RNG seeding

Tags: java, random, numbers, seed

My question concerns the Java RNG; use the following code:

```
for (int s = 0; s < 600; s++) {
   Random r = new Random(s);
   System.out.println(r.nextDouble());
   System.out.println(r.nextDouble() + "\n-----");
}
```

This will result in 600 random numbers being generated. I know this is a bit odd, but I require a new random number generator each time in my actual project. The seed I receive is sequential. The first random double that is generated is extremely close for any of the seeds, is this because of the linear congruential formula that is used as initialization?

The second double generated actually looks like it is actually properly random, is this safe to assume so? Is it OK practice to first generate an unused random number, and after that moment start to use it for the actual reason it was created?

Thank you in advance

EDIT:

Let me clarify:

```
int possibleRoutes = 7;
void handlePacket(Packet p) {

    int chosenRoute = p.hash % possibleRoutes;
    // ...Other code...

}
```

vs.

```
int possibleRoutes = 7;
void handlePacket(Packet p) {

    Random r = new Random(p.hash);
    int chosenRoute = r.nextInt() % possibleRoutes;
    // ...Other code...
}
```

}

vs.

```
int possibleRoutes = 7;
void handlePacket(Packet p) {

    Random r = new Random(p.hash);
    r.nextInt();
    int chosenRoute = r.nextInt() % possibleRoutes;
    // ...Other code...

}
```

A guarantee is that each packet *must* take the same route. The packet hash is inherently sequential at the moment. There are too many possible hashes to keep any type of state to speed this up.

Comment: I don't get this usage. A PRNG has a state. Just create one (outside; if you need, based on the time) and sample within the loop. The second call will be based on a different state as the first. No reseeding needed. (reseeding within a loop is bad practice in almost all use-cases). Throwing aways RNG-numbers is also only done in some very complex settings and is not the approach to pursue here.

Comment: To be safe here: tell us, why you need a new PRNG-object in each loop (if that's what you want) or if you only need new numbers each time the program is called.

Comment: WHY do you think you need a new random number generator on each iteration?  Statements like this often reflect a deep level of misunderstanding about PRNGs.

Comment: I added the pseudo-code of the real case to the original question

Comment: The second example looks fine to me (assuming some quality of the PRNG). Third is just throwing away stuff (because you think the first one is bad). Stick with 2. *Warning*: 2 and 3 are only okay, if the hashes returned are satisfying the PRNGs assumptions about the seed. (example not bound to java: PRNG wants 32 bit seed, your hash is 16 bit = trouble) It should also be possible to reseed some base-PRNG without creating a new object (better!). Task-assumption: two identical packets (accord. to hash) should take the same route; but route-chosing should be random. This is my understanding here.

Comment: @sascha Ah, reseeding might be faster, yes. The 2nd one is not okay, because the nextInt() will nearly always be one of the outcomes because of the linear relation talked about in the other comment section (it will first produces a lot of 0000000 before it then reaches the linear threshold for the next and then produce a lot of 1111111, etc.).

Comment: You should not be able to observe something like this with the 2nd example (that dramatic / easily). It looks like some other problem within your code. So check your hashing. And if you really think LCG is the problem here, just use something else. Usage keeps the same.

Comment: In essence, the PRNG does a rehash of the original sequential "hash". If you run the original code sample, the first number it outputs is very sequentially correlated.

Comment: And some easier/alternative approach: shuffle your routes randomly (through a lib-function). And just use the hash to index this shuffled container.

Comment: If your code fails that bad, it looks the hash is more the problem. Well, you can show some complete outputs. The problems mentioned by pjs should diminish completely with given the hash as complete seeding/state = all the bits needed although it's now questionale if PRNGs are needed (see the shuffle-approach)! . **Actually that's very important** How do you hash? Analyze this first!

Comment: You're correct, in retrospect the hash is the true problem; "is a PRNG capable of converting a sequential hash to a uniformly mapped hash?" should've been the question. Reshuffle of routes and storing that state is too much (~1-10M src-dst pairs with e.g. 100 routes would results in ~1-10GB of main memory). Thank you for the effort to respond and discuss with me

Comment: Still a bit unclear. Why src-dst pairs. It looks like you are indexing routes. There are probably less than 2^32 routes or your code above does not make much sense. But well... you know the dangers know. If your routes are indexable (e.g. choose one in [0, 100000) one of the best approaches would be using a very good hash (not the built-in simple ones which might do something like concatenating int-hashes for arrays) like SHA-256 (yes, you will lose performance) and use this for indexing. As you will get 256 bits, you might truncate (should be ok) or use something stronger to map to your inds.

Comment: Side-note: given a well-working hash which is then mapped to your route-indices range, shuffling is also not needed, but would be minimally more robust to some potential defects.

Comment: Let's say the case where you have two nodes, a packet arrives at node A, A has K neighbors it can send it to (which are on a shortest path to the destination), it does packet.hash % K to choose the path, and then passes it to node B (also K neighbors), which also does packet.hash % K to decide the path. This means that they will always select the same index if they have the same amount of K neighbors to choose from. So they would need to adapt the packet.hash locally in such a way that this causation no longer exists, so that the packets can have K*K possibilities to go on Vs. only K.

Comment: Not a simple task and well...i think i explained enough for now (and hope you can solve your problem). Just one more remark: your explanation sounds like you need to make a lot of random-decisions, based on one start-seed. So the basic approach is: take the packet; hash it with something good (need to build a string/bytearray first, then use SHA-256 for example). Prepare the hash for seeding your PRNG (you need 48 bits; you got 256; truncation is easy, try it first; other approaches are better) and use this one-time-created PRNG for all your neighbor-based decisions (no rehashing/reseeding).

Comment: Thank you for the discussion, I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

why do you give a special number as a seed? just leave it empty, so the Random constructor will choose a seed for you.

```
for (int s = 0; s < 600; s++) {
     Random r = new Random();
     System.out.println(r.nextDouble());
     System.out.println(r.nextDouble() + "\n-----");
   }
```

see [Role of seed in random number generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25795035/role-of-seed-in-random-number-generation)

Comment: It must be deterministically runnable again

Answer (score 0):

Call the default constructor which uses the nanoTime as a seed. This way you won't need to generate a new seed to create your object each iteration.

```
//loop through number of numbers needed
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i +)
    //Calls default constructor
    Random r = new Random();
    System.out.println(r.nextDouble()*.5);
```

Comment: So why not reuse the Random-object? (=creating it outside of the loop). This looks very inefficient (especially for MersenneTwister or anything which uses a huge state).

Comment: From my understanding this user wants to reseed for each number generated(in which i agree with you i would never reseed inside a loop or even this often) I'm going off of this quote "I require a new random number generator each time in my actual project"

Comment: Fair enough. I don't know if he is missing some basics or if there is a misunderstanding.

Comment: @sascha Java's default `Random` implementation is not a Mersenne Twister, it's a 48 bit linear congruential generator.

Comment: @pjs Interesting. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @sascha That's probably why OP is asking about using the second output, the first results of sequentially seeded LCG values will be linearly related other than a small number of wrap-arounds due to the modulo operation.

Comment: @pjs That sounds like a combination of awful initialization based on the seed and the internal-state-space. But well, i remember MT to have some seeding/state issues as well. So you say the LCG-behaviour in this regard is so bad, that it's directly observed in such simple code? (e.g. always growing 2 times...) That's interesting. Always fascinating to observe default-PRNGs in different programming-environments and the problems with changing them to be more modern (e.g. numpy sticking to MT; which is not that good anymore). Luckily one can always stick to external libraries if needed.

Comment: @sascha So even if the initial results are linearly related, any subsequent results will be pseudo-random quality?

Comment: @IsNiska First work on your understanding of basic PRNG usage before doing anything else. As said by me and others: the usage represented looks very wrong! The next question is a tough one. Analyzing the randomness of PRNGs is hard. It looks java uses one of the oldest (and arguably best analyzed) methods with some drawbacks in regards to randomness. While its sure, that modern PRNGs are better, it's hard to reason about if these drawbacks are a problem for you. In general: yes, java's random is designed to give you random numbers. As i never use LCGs, i can't estimate the problem here.

Comment: @sascha In this case I actually need a function that hashes a linearly-fed input in such a way that the outcome is uniform among the possibilities - I use the PRNG as it seemed rather logical to fulfill the requirement.

Comment: @IsNiska Your task is still unclear. If it's about the packet-hashes, using the seed is the right way. If the packets arrive in the same order (and two hash-equal packets can take diff. routes), no reseeding is needed ever. Remember, there is a state.

Comment: @sascha Yes, but two hash-equal packets are not allowed to take different routes, because of congestion control mechanisms that rely on a single route through the network.

Comment: @IsNiska Then maybe make that clear for once. How hard is it to describe the setting exactly (in the original post!!!)? Don't make us guess.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use a master random to seed all the subsiduary randoms in the loop:

```
Random masterRand = new Random();
for (int s = 0; s < 600; s++) {
  Random r = new Random(masterRand.nextLong());
  System.out.println(r.nextDouble());
  System.out.println(r.nextDouble() + "\n-----");
}
```

Comment: Why is this any better than going with a single `Random` outside the loop?  Both are fully predictable, but this one is more convoluted and expensive.

Comment: I assumed that the questioner wanted multiple copies of `Random`.  Sometimes time-based seeding can give identical seeds/sequences if the loop processes quickly enough.  This method avoids that.  Also, this method allows repeatability: if you provide an explicit seed for `masterRand` you can repeat exactly the same run of seeds if you wish.  This can be useful for debugging and other purposes.

Comment: Yes, but you get  avoidance of repeat seeding and repeatability by just using `masterRand` for your `nextDouble()`s, without the needless expense of creating a bunch of one-use `Random`s.  Still waiting to hear why OP thinks they want a new generator each time...

Comment: I added the pseudo-code of the real case to the original question